# How to enable "New Folder" under Team Discussion?

Tags: discussion-board, folder, grouping

I'm quite new to SharePoint. Currently running SharePoint 2010 in our office. I need to setup folders in the Team Discussion so we can group various topics under each folder. I saw the New Folder button is being greyed out. I can't find any way under the settings to enable it.

I might no need the folder actually, all I need is the ability to group various topics under 1 root topics.

Btw, can someone also explain the normal hierarchy structure for discussion. Like Root->Topic->Discussion->Message or something similar, as I saw under Content Type, there's Discussion and Message, but not sure how they relate to each others

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a column that would represent all of your topics.  This could be a choice column that you would use to edit the properties of the discussion.  Then, you could create a view that groups all discussions based on their topic.  You will have the same data all automatically categorized.

For the hierarchy, a message can only be created when you are under the context of a discussion.  It is how you can manage data that has behaviour that looks a lot like master/detail.

Comment: Cool idea. I'll wait a little while and see if there's any other solution